# Insert phrase into database

Tags: database

Want to solve next task. Or get some understanding of.

1. You have text, for example
2. You want to insert it into database word by word (for statistics, fast changes, word searching and etc).
3. You want to render it back correctly
4. You want to change words order in phrase

My suggestions:

`Table WORD (id, string)`

`Table PHRASE (id, ending)    // Ending - for example, comma, dot, question etc`

`Table PHRASE_WORDS (order, phrase_id, word_id, decoration)    // Decoration - special instructions to change render behavior: capitals, small, abbreviation, etc.`

Order is the most difficult part. Is it right way and the most optimized (natural) to represent phrases like that?

Maybe there is more correct way to do something like that? Or maybe some articles to check?

For example *The quick brown fox jumps over THE lazy dog.*

Table WORDs

```
id  string   
1   'the'    
2   'quick'  
...
```

Table PHRASEs

```
id ending
1   dot
...
```

Table PHRASE_WORDS

```
order phrase_id word_id decoration
1      1         1       none        // the
2      1         2       none        // quick
3      1         3       none        // brown
...
7      1         1       capitals    // THE
```

And render it through 'order' column.

How to optimize this to change 'order'? Because now you must render it, change it, clear related `PHRASE_WORDS` entries and parse it back into table.

What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to clear the related PHRASE_WORDS? I would think it's enough if you change the values in the order column. If you switch the worlds 'the' and 'quick' for example then you just write 2 in the first row and 1 in the second. Am I missing something?

Comment: So I'm trying to find some "right" way to make changes in words order.
Now I have to render all the text (or part to change), change, clear db and parse whole text back. Is it only way?

Comment: I am sorry I still fail to see why you have to 'clear db'. Can you explain the reason?

Comment: How to parse back edited text? I think I have to clear corresponding tables.